# Request status of Zebra printer using Python

Tags: python, windows, usb, zebra-printers

I'm using a **Zebra** ZD220T printer connected through **USB** to print some labels.

To send the label in ZPL format to the printer I'm using Zebra package:

```
from zebra import Zebra

z = Zebra('printer_name')
z.output(my_label)
```

Everything is working fine to this point.

What I'm trying to achieve, is to get the **printer status** right before sending a new label for printing.

The package I'm using doesn't support bi-directional communications.

I'm trying to send the command "~HS" to get the status of the printer and read back its status.

Any ideas on how to do this?

The OS is **Windows** 10 and the **Python** version is 3.7.